# User names in TFS 2018 data warehouse SSRS reports

Tags: tfs

I am trying to build SSRS reports using TFS_Datawarehouse on TFS 2018 v1.1.
DimPerson table doesn't have all the user id's displayed as "S-1-5-21-2580684728-4277449090-3224694807-1320". Can someone help me with pulling the actual user names?

Thanks much!!

Comment: Hi Patrick, we solved this by accessing the information on TFS_Configuration database. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample of DimPerson table. It is filled with SID's and normal names. All Date boxes are empty and lots of SID Instead of people:

[image: Dim.Person]

Some of SID's in AD have normal names. But here are they presented by SID. This is make sense not all users have a display name such as some service account. You could double confirm this info in the SQL database of TFS.

If the result is no the same, you could try to reconfigured Analysis and Reporting features.